# sourcemap support in webstorm for unit test

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

How to setup webstorm to support source map for karma tests. The `js` file is generated through typescript compiler.

I added the source map too to the karma conf file.

```
files: [
            'common/ext/lodash.min.js',
            '.tmp/tests/unit.js',
            '.tmp/tests/unit.js.map'
        ],
```

Looks like it is loading as it hits the brakpoint in typescript file, BUT, gets an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
at http://localhost:9876/base/.tmp/tests/unit.js.map?94f7...f22b6:1
```

isn't a sourcemap file a valid json file? so why this error. Any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Seems including the .map files in files[] is the only way for now... I've also tried the [karma-typescript-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-typescript-preprocessor), but it doesn't currently work due to https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/990

Comment: Including the .map files results in an error in the tests though, any other way?

Comment: you can try the karma-typescript-preprocessor. The above mentioned bug is fixed, so it works fine now. The only issue using it in WebStorm is that 'jump to source' from test results doesn't work - [WEB-13083](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13083)